# Integration by substitution specific question

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I have a question regarding integrating a indefinite integral, I keep on getting the incorrect answer, and I do not know how I would be able to acquire the right answer.

The question is : $\int \dfrac{x}{x+3} dx$

I keep getting the answer: $x+3 -3\ln(x+3)$

I apologise if this is a simple question.

Thank you

Comment: Apart from a missing $+C$ this is a right answer. You can check by differentiating  Another right answer is $x-3\ln(x+3)+C$.

Comment: @André Nicolas, but a online software says the answer is: x-3in(x+3)' with the constant of integration ( I forgot about that). Cheers

Comment: If $f(x)+C$  is a right answer, and $f(x)$  and $g(x)$ differ by a constant, then $g(x)+C$ is a right answer.  But if a piece of software is poorly designed, it may not know that.

Answer (score 3):

Since we have $$\frac{x}{x+3} = \frac{x+3 - 3}{x+3} = 1 - \frac{3}{x+3}$$ then it follows immediately that $$\bbox[10px, border: blue 1px solid]{\int \frac{x}{x+3} \, \mathrm{d}x = x - 3 \ln |x+3| + c}$$

This agrees with your answer since your extra constant term can simple be absorbed into your arbitrary constant, i.e: you can write $$x+3 -3 \ln |x+3| + c =x - 3 \ln |x+3| + d$$ where $d = c+3$.

Answer (score 0):

The indefinite integral is defined less to a constant, because it is a function whose derivative is the integrand function and the derivative of a constant is $0$.

So writing correctly your result you have the integral function: $F(x)=x+3-3\ln|x+3| +C$ and this is the same as $F(x)=x-3\ln|x+3|+C'$, with $3+C=C'$ , anyway a constant.